# existential quantifier of an equivalence

Tags: logic, quantifiers

the exercise asks: what is the value ( T or F ) of this proposition:

- $∃x, (2x+4=0\:\text{ is equivalent to }\:x=-2)$

Where x belongs to the natural numbers.

---

My train of thought:

- regardless of the values of x the equivalency is true
- however, I cannot determine a natural number that verifies this equivalence therefore I cannot state that the proposition is true.
- If I say this proposition is true then x belongs to Ø
- Can I do this?:
  $(∃x, 2x+4=0)$ is equivalent to $(∃x, x =-2) $
  and therefore  $F$ is equivalent to $F$ which is $T$.

Comment: $x=-2$ satisfy the equivalence.

Comment: x belongs to the natural numbers

Comment: If $x$ must belongs to naturals, $2x+4=0$ is always False, and also $x=-2$ is always false. Thus, the two are equivalent

Comment: i realized i was overthinking this

Answer (score 1):

$\exists x\in \Bbb N\, (2x+4=0\iff x=-2),$ partly unabbreviated, is $\exists x\,(x\in \Bbb N\land [2x+4=0 \iff x=-2]).$ Now  $A\iff B$ is an abbreviation for $(A\land B)\lor (\,[\neg A]\land [\neg B]\,).$ So we have $$\exists x\,(x\in \Bbb N \land [(2x+4=0\land x=-2)\lor (2x+4\ne 0\land x\ne -2)]\,).$$ This is true if $\exists x\in \Bbb N $ is true because if $x\in \Bbb N$ then $(2x+4\ne 0\land x\ne -2).$

Comment: Sometimes it's better to not think, and let the math do itself.